# Is there any way to group non child elements in xslt?

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an xml file that has the following tree structure:

```
<foo attr1=""/>
<foo2 num="1"/>
<foo2 num="2"/>
<foo2 num="3"/>
<foo2 num="4"/>
<foo attr1=""/>
<foo2 num="1"/>
...
```

As you can see the element foo2 is not a child element of foo but I would like to
group the foo2 num="1" thru num="4" with the first foo ocurrence. There is no
attribute in none of them that I could use as a reference either...

Is there any way to achieve this with xsl?

I have succeeded with looping through all the foo's occurrences with ease(using xsl:for-each attribute) but the tricky part is to include the following foo2 elements for each foo loop.

EDIT:
Lets pretend attr has a random value such as:

```
<foo attr1="abc"/>
<foo2 num="1"/>
<foo2 num="2"/>
<foo2 num="3"/>
<foo2 num="4"/>
<foo attr1="def"/>
<foo2 num="1"/>
```

What I want to do is group abc and the following foo's in a table so that:

```
+--------+-----+
| abc    | def |
| 1      |   1 |
| 2      |     |
| 3      |     |
| 4      |     |
+--------------+
```

No unfortunately it doesn't support xslt 2.0.

Comment: **1.** Your question is not entirely clear. Please show us the expected output. **2.** Does your processor support XSLT 2.0?

Comment: @michael.hor257k I just updated my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two separate problems here:

1. How to group the nodes, using an equivalent of XSLT 2.0's `group-starting-with`;
2. How to transpose (pivot) the result, so that you can build a table where each group occupies a *column* - even though an HTML table is constructed *row-by-row*.

I would suggest you do this in two passes:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
extension-element-prefixes="exsl">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="grp" match="foo2" use="generate-id(preceding-sibling::foo[1])" />

<!-- first-pass -->
<xsl:variable name="groups-rtf">
    <xsl:for-each select="root/foo">
        <group name="{@attr1}">
            <xsl:for-each select="key('grp', generate-id())">
                <item><xsl:value-of select="@num"/></item>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </group>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="groups" select="exsl:node-set($groups-rtf)/group" />

<xsl:template match="/">
    <table border="1">
        <!-- header row -->
        <tr>
            <xsl:for-each select="$groups">
                <th><xsl:value-of select="@name"/></th>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </tr>       
        <!-- data rows -->
        <xsl:call-template name="generate-rows"/>
    </table>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="generate-rows">
    <xsl:param name="i" select="1"/>
    <xsl:if test="$groups/item[$i]">
        <tr>
            <xsl:for-each select="$groups">
                <td><xsl:value-of select="item[$i]"/></td>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </tr>
        <xsl:call-template name="generate-rows">
            <xsl:with-param name="i" select="$i + 1"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applied to the following example input:

**XML**

```
<root>
    <foo attr1="abc"/>
    <foo2 num="1"/>
    <foo2 num="2"/>
    <foo2 num="3"/>
    <foo2 num="4"/>
    <foo attr1="def"/>
    <foo2 num="5"/>
    <foo2 num="6"/>
</root>
```

the (rendered) result will be:

[image]